What is the image of God in Genesis?
In the Genesis accounts of creation, God executes a plan he has had to create man in his image and give him authority over the earth.
Genesis 1:26

Then God said, “Let us make man in our image, after our likeness. And let them have dominion over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the heavens and over the livestock and over all the earth and over every creeping thing that creeps on the earth.”

The phrase image has been used to describe Jesus in the new testament, so what's the meaning of image, is it what makes us different from the rest of the visible creation or it has some other meanings?

In Genesis, the word translated as "man" is אָדָ֛ם - adam. An interesting thing about "adam" as God's image is the next line: "male and female he created them." The image of God in Genesis is male and female.
This raises a new question with regard to Jesus as the "last Adam" (1 Corinthians 15:45) and image of God (2 Corinthians 4:4). Was there to be a second Eve as his counterpart? Did his Mother fulfill this role? Did the church do so as his Bride? Was there a unknown woman would would have been God's daughter as Jesus was God's son?
The OP asks if the word "image" implies humanity's uniqueness as compared to the rest of creation. The answer is yes. The rest of creation does reflect God's nature (Romans 1:20) but not to the degree that human beings do. Other creatures lack free will and creativity. Human beings can respond freely to God's love and even cooperate with God in perfecting ourselves. (Matthew 5:44) Even angels do not do this. They also do not seem to have been created in God's "image" in the sense of being male and female, or having the potential to experience God's parental heart of unconditional love, as humans can.

Did you mean not to the degree that humans do instead of not to the degree than humans do, your welcome.

freewill, knowledge, understanding and other things that the creatures do not have is what makes God say we are made in his image , what about apperance? Could it mean that God is in the likeness of man?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany... thanks for pointing out the typo. Some people do believe that  human beings represent God in external form as well as internal character. The text can indeed be read that way.

Thanks for your answer Dan, how is human free will different from that of am animal? Is it because an animal cannot will to break the will of God while humans can?

@DongLi. I have not heard of animals having free will. Instinct is what they have.
